# A question regarding symmetry properties of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation

Was anyone able to explain why $$E(U_2) = 0$$

I don't quite understand what the relevance of the underlined statement - "by the symmetry of $U_1$" in determining $E(U_2)$ is [image]

**edit**: I get it now, was brain dead on the night of asking this question.
thanks for the responses anyway

Comment: Could you please state the book from which this exercise is taken? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: how are the distributions of $U_2$ and $-U_2$ related? What does that imply about how their expectations are related?

Comment: The textbook is making a lot of fuss over nothing. Since $U_1$ and $U_2$ are _independent_, $E[U_2\mid U_1] = E[U_2]$ without the necessity of dragging in covariances (which might not even exist). The only issue here is why $E[U_2] = 0$ and the reason given for this, while perfectly correct in this simple situation, need not apply in general: symmetry of the density need not mean that $E[U] = 0$ as [the well-known example of Cauchy random variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36027/6633) shows.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am confused as to why $U_1 \neq 0$ and $U_2$ equals zero? Aren't they just arbitrary random variables with the same distribution?

Comment: @COOLSerdash it's from a homework question.

Comment: @whuber $U_2$ and $-U_2$ have the same distribution?

Comment: The statement "... $E[U_2]=0$ by symmetry of $f_{U_1}$." has the obvious typo that it should have said "$f_{U_2}$."

Comment: FWIW, the duplicate was found as the first relevant hit in a site search for [distribution symmetry expectation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=distribution%20symmetry%20expectation). The next hit I could find is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46843, which directly addresses a generalization of the present question (to all odd moments).  (Most of the other hits do not discuss symmetry *per se*, but only invoke it without further comment.)