# Understanding "the kernel has zero mean"

Tags: mean, density-function, kernel-smoothing, nonparametric-density

I am trying to understand kernel density estimation and found the graphic below illustrating different kernel functions on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29#Some_of_the_kernels_mentioned_above_in_a_common_coordinate_system). I have no trouble reconciling it with the two statements

1. "the kernel integrates to one", i.e. $\int K(z)\mathrm{d}z=1$, and
2. "the kernel is symmetric around zero", i.e. $K(z)=K(-z)$.

But I've several times seen the statement **"the kernel has zero mean"** and I  can't make sense out of it.

Does it mean

1. $\mathbb{E}[K(z)]=\int K(z)z\mathrm{d}z=0$ or
2. something else entirely?

[image: Some common kernels]

Comment: The first thing.

Comment: Why this property of zero mean of a kernel is important in kernel density estimation?

Comment: @xeon Otherwise, the convolution of the kernel with a distribution changes the location. That can be compensated by subtracting the kernel's mean from the result--which is identical to centering the kernel at a zero mean in the first place. So, no importance whatsoever is attached to having a zero mean, but it is useless to have a nonzero mean.

Comment: Note that symmetry (property 2) together with the existence of a first moment of $K$ implies that moment must be zero: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46843.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first statement is almost, but not entirely correct. $K$ is a density function and what we mean when we refer to the mean of the density function $K$ is
$$\int K(z)z\mathrm{d}z.$$
Similarly, the variance of $K$ is
$$\int K(z)z^2\mathrm{d}z.$$
So, it doesn't make any sense to write $\mathbb{E}[K(z)]$. Rather, the statement "the kernel has zero mean" should be formally written as
$$\int K(z)z\mathrm{d}z=0.$$
(Thanks, [Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152591/understanding-the-kernel-has-zero-mean?noredirect=1#comment291070_152591)!)