# Should we teach kurtosis in an applied statistics course? If so, how?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, kurtosis, teaching, l-moments

Central tendency, spread and skewness can all be defined relatively well, at least on an intuitive basis; the standard mathematical measures of these things also correspond relatively well to our intuitive notions. But kurtosis seems to be different. It's very confusing and it doesn't match well with any intuition about distributional shape.

A typical explanation of kurtosis in an applied setting would be this extract from *Applied statistics for business and management using Microsoft Excel* $^{[1]}$:

> Kurtosis refers to how peaked a distribution is or conversely how flat it is. If there are more data values in the tails, than what you expect from a normal distribution, the kurtosis is positive. Conversely if there are less data values in the tails, than you would expect in a normal distribution, the kurtosis is negative. Excel cannot calculate this statistic unless you have at least four data values.

Aside from the confusion between "kurtosis" and "excess kurtosis" (as in this book, it is common to use the former word to refer to what others author call the latter), the interpretation in terms of "peakedness" or "flatness" is then muddled by the switch of attention to how many items of data are in the tails. Considering both "peak" and "tails" is necessary — Kaplansky$^{[2]}$ complained in 1945 that many textbooks of the time erroneously stated kurtosis was to do with how high the peak of the distribution is compared to that of a normal distribution, without considering the tails. But clearly having to consider the shape both at the peak and in the tails makes the intuition harder to grasp, a point the extract quoted above skips over by seguing from peakedness to heaviness of tails as if these concepts were the same.

Moreover this classical "peak and tails" explanation of kurtosis only works well for symmetric and unimodal distributions (indeed, the illustrated examples in that text are all symmetric). [Yet the "correct" general way to interpret kurtosis, whether in terms of "peaks", "tails" or "shoulders", has been disputed for decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Interpretation).$^{[2][3][4][5][6]}$

Is there an intuitive way of teaching kurtosis in an applied setting which will not hit contradictions or counterexamples when a more rigorous approach is taken? Is kurtosis even a useful concept at all in the context of these kind of applied data analysis courses, as opposed to in mathematical statistics classes? If "peakedness" of a distribution is an intuitively useful concept, should we teach it by way of [L-moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-moment)$^{[7]}$ instead?

$[1]$ Herkenhoff, L. and Fogli, J. (2013). *Applied statistics for business and management using Microsoft Excel*. New York, NY: Springer.

$[2]$ Kaplansky, I. (1945). "A common error concerning kurtosis".
*Journal of the American Statistical Association*, **40**(230): 259.

$[3]$ Darlington, Richard B (1970). "Is Kurtosis Really 'Peakedness'?". *The American Statistician* **24**(2): 19–22

$[4]$ Moors, JJA. (1986) "The meaning of kurtosis: Darlington reexamined". *The American Statistician* **40**(4): 283–284

$[5]$ Balanda, Kevin P. and MacGillivray, H.L. (1988). "[Kurtosis: A Critical Review". *The American Statistician*](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kevin_Balanda/publication/230872574_Kurtosis_A_Critical_Review/links/0f31752de77e8d1c95000000.pdf) **42**(2): 111–119

$[6]$ DeCarlo, L. T. (1997). "[On the meaning and use of kurtosis](http://www.columbia.edu/~ld208/psymeth97.pdf)". *Psychological methods*, **2**(3), 292. Chicago

$[7]$ Hosking, J.R.M. (1992). "Moments or L moments? An example comparing two measures of distributional shape". The American Statistician **46**(3): 186–189

Comment: What do you mean by the usual curricula? I.e. what level of education.

Comment: What exactly are you teaching about kurtosis? This question is pretty vague as it is. Please fill out how it fits into your curricula now and perhaps some intuitive examples from the standard measures you agree with that are contradicted in kurtosis.

Comment: I would not miss teaching it, and sure love to hear about anything that helps me motivate in my teaching why it is a useful part of the course (in my case: undergraduate business/economics students)

Comment: I don't think the moment measure of kurtosis is actually much different than moment skewness in that respect. In both cases they don't really reflect what people think they do, and they're both less intuitive than the stories people tell themselves about them. For every surprising counterexample I have about kurtosis, I have another one about skewness. I wouldn't remove either of them, but I'd reduce the emphasis on the moment measures, I'd move them later and change the way they're taught, so that we don't conflate different concepts and we don't make claims that don't hold up.

Comment: @Glen_b  Interesting! I've seen some of your kurtosis examples but I don't recall seeing examples of counterintuitive skewness.

Comment: I believe I recall you commenting under one of my posts about skewness (a while back now). I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Your memory is better than mine.

Comment: It may have been [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89382/in-left-skewed-data-what-is-the-relationship-between-mean-and-median) perhaps; you at least seem to express mild surprise there.

Comment: Thanks!  But I think there is still more intuition behind skew than kurtosis. The example there had slight negative skewness and (to the extent a density plot is useful with N = 6) did have a longer left tail.

Comment: Higher skewness *doesn't* imply a heavier tail in the direction of skewness. Zero skewness doesn't mean symmetry (all odd moments zero doesn't even imply symmetry). Symmetry doesn't even imply zero skewness. What intuitions are left?

Comment: This is not to imply I think skewness is valueless (though some people do); it's just not necessarily carrying the information people think it does.

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125084/does-mean-median-imply-that-a-unimodal-distribution-is-symmetric)'s another answer with some discussion that has an interesting class of examples.  There's some others but I don't see them right now. Some of whuber's posts are also useful.

Comment: I think the question would benefit from something of a rewrite: perhaps if it established the "myths" that get taught, demonstrated their falsity, then asked "so what is left to teach?" or "is there a *correct* intuition we could teach?" That might help with clarity concerns, though obviously this is Peter's question not mine and only he knows what the nub of the question is. (I'm not sure whether it's answerable at the moment precisely because I can't work out what the nub is. But I think this has the potential to be an excellent and interesting Q&A, with some work.)

Comment: I made it community wiki so it is really everyone's question.  I think @Silverfish raises some good points here.

Comment: For the close voters: consider my answer before you vote for close. I will vote for keeping open!

Comment: It would be a shame if this discussion were closed! @Glen_b, I read up on the links posted here, which are very useful. I do not think I saw an example for your assertion that "symmetry doesn't even imply zero skewness" and it would seem to me that it contradicts whuber's answer given [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46843/central-moments-of-symmetric-distributions). (I understand it is a little off-topic as we talk about kurtosis here, so I can post it elsewhere, if you prefer.) Does whuber's answer maybe (tacitly?) apply to continuous distributions only?

Comment: An advantage of (temporary) closure is it gives time to get the question "right" before answers come in - once there are lots of answers it is harder to reframe the question. So I don't think people who fear the current Q is unclear should be afraid to vote close, as that isn't the end of the discussion at all!

Comment: I think it might be helpful to reframe the question as "how should we teach kurtosis" rather than "whether" - I think that's more likely to produce fruitful answers. Economists often talk about "stylized facts" - sweeping generalizations that miss off fine details but are good rules of thumb. I think a key issue with skewness and kurtosis is that the stylized facts that are often taught in applied courses do not tally well with the mathematical truth taught in a more technical course ...

Comment: I think the changes suggested by @Silverfish would improve this question.

Comment: @ChistophHanck Consider the Cauchy, which is certainly symmetric. What's it's standardized third moment? If we add  some qualification, it can be made into a true statement, but as usually put, it's false.

Comment: @Silverfish feel free to change the question in the ways you suggest

Comment: I have had a go at re-writing the question as I suggested. By trying to clarify the question I wonder if what I have written is, in part, the germ of an answer (in which case feel someone should feel free to cut those parts out and perhaps place them in an answer instead!). I suspect the question would benefit from a "typical" counterexample (e.g. a graph that shows a distribution for which the quoted book explanation is unhelpful or misleading) but that is something @Glen_b could likely do better than me!

Comment: @SIlverfish - Parts of that do look like an answer. I think that a "typical" counterexample would be a good thing to do, but since I've been busy rejecting the premise of the question (in that it tries to draw a distinction between kurtosis and skewness) I'd kind of like to know what information Peter would teach about *skewness* that would not be similarly problematic. I really don't think there's very much of a distinction and I'd urge greater caution with both. Perhaps I should answer on that basis (mostly in comments already).

Comment: @Glen_b Part of the premise of the original question I felt uncomfortable about (but have left mostly unchanged in my edit) is "Central tendency, spread and skewness can all be defined relatively well, at least on an intuitive basis; the standard mathematical measures of these things also correspond relatively well to our intuitive notions." As you say, I'm not sure that actually *is* true for skew! But I'd agree with Peter that in some ways kurtosis seems "worse". I can eyeball a distribution and often get the sign of skew right, but sign of (excess) kurtosis I'd be less confident to judge

Comment: @Silverfish Best to leave the premise alone, probably; that can be put in an answer. Certainly a counterexample to the statement from the book is easy enough to construct following the same sort of approach as in the answer that led to this question (I also shudder at the use of "less" there in the quote; the way they phrased it they intend "fewer" but in fact they should say something else altogether; every few words raises more objections).  ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... Given the need to interpret and explain the quote and then why what it's trying to say is wrong, For example as framed it's a statement about *data*, in which case we're talking about sample skewness / kurtosis and sample "tails" ... and in that case the question gets a lot harder. it may be best to leave the whole thing for an answer. An answer that denies both the premise of the question and the quote will be long indeed. It may take some days before I get to finish it. Incidentally, a correctly formed "shoulders" statement is undeniable, since its a statement of a mathematical fact.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, didn't want to change the fundamental premise of the question, just to try and give the question a bit more "shape" and specificity. (As an aside, the ["less vs fewer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fewer_vs._less) argument is centuries-old, and I think even many prescriptivists would admit their historical case is very weak in this one. But that part could really have been phrased better.)

Comment: Skewness does indeed tell you whether one tail is heavier than another. Consider $V = \{(X-\mu)/\sigma\}^3$, whose distribution balances at the skewness of $X$. Put a fulcrum at $v=0$. If $p_V(v)$ falls to the left, then skewness of $X$ is <0, and its left tail, when amplified through the cubic function, is heavier (more precisely, has more *leverage*) than the right tail. If the distribution $p_V(v)$ falls to the right, than skewness of $X$ is >0, and the left tail, when amplified through the cubic function, is lighter (more precisely, has less *leverage*), than the right tail.

Answer (score 21):

Kurtosis is really pretty simple ... and useful. It is simply a measure of outliers, or tails. It has nothing to do with the peak whatsoever - that definition must be abandoned.

Here is a data set:
0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 999

Notice that '999' is an outlier.

Here are the $z^4$ values from the data set:

0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00,0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 360.98

Notice that only the outlier gives a $z^4$ that is noticeably different from 0.

The average of these $z^4$ values is the kurtosis of the empirical distribution (subtract 3 if you like, it doesn't matter for the point I am making): 18.05

It should be obvious from this calculation that the data near the "peak" (the non-outlier data) contribute almost nothing to the kurtosis statistic.

Kurtosis is useful as a measure of outliers. Outliers are important to elementary students and therefore kurtosis should be taught. But kurtosis has virtually nothing to do with the peak, whether it is pointy, flat, bimodal or infinite.  You can have all the above with small kurtosis and all of the above with large kurtosis.  So it should *NEVER* be presented as having anything to do with the peak, because that will be teaching incorrect information.  It also makes the material needless confusing, and seemingly less useful.

Summary:

1. kurtosis is useful as a measures of tails (outliers).
2. kurtosis has nothing to do with the peak.
3. kurtosis is practically useful and should be taught, but only as a measure of outliers. Do not mention peak when teaching kurtosis.

This article explains clearly why the "Peakedness" definition is now officially dead.

Westfall, P.H. (2014). "[Kurtosis as Peakedness, 1905 – 2014. R.I.P.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4321753/)" *The American Statistician*, **68**(3), 191–195.

Comment: Welcome to CV, I hope you stick around and contribute more in future! I have edited your post to include a link to the paper and reformatted some of the math notation, I hope you don't mind. (By placing math in a `$` e.g. `$z^4$` it's possible to use $\LaTeX$.)

Answer (score 6):

While the question is somewhat vague, it is interesting.  At what levels is kurtosis taught?  I remember it being mentioned in a (master's level) course in linear models (long time ago, based on first edition of Seber's book).  It was not an important topic, but it enters in topics like studying the (lack of) robustness of the Likelihood ratio test (F-test) of equality of variances, where (from memory) correct level asymptotically depends on having same kurtosis as the normal distribution, which is too much to assume!   We saw a paper (but I never read it with details) http://www.jstor.org/stable/4615828?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents  by Oja, which tries to find out what skewness, kurtosis and such really measures.

Why do I find this interesting?  Because I have been teaching in latin america, where it seems that skewness & kurtosis are taught by many as important topics, and trying to tell post-graduate students (many from economy) that kurtosis is a bad measure of form of a distribution (mainly because sampling variability of fourth powers simply is to large), was difficult.  I was trying getting them to use QQplots instead. So,  to some of the commenters, yes, this **is taught** someplaces, probably to much!

By the way, this is not only my opinion.  The following blog post https://www.spcforexcel.com/knowledge/basic-statistics/are-skewness-and-kurtosis-useful-statistics    contains this citation (attributed to Dr. Wheeler):

> In short, skewness and kurtosis are practically worthless.  Shewhart
>   made this observation in his first book. The statistics for skewness
>   and kurtosis simply do not provide any useful information beyond that
>   already given by the measures of location and dispersion.

We should teach better techniques to study forms of distributions! such as QQplots (or relative distribution plots).  And, if somebody still needs numerical measures, measures based on L-moments are better.  I will quote one passage from the paper J R Statist Soc B (1990) 52, No 1, pp 105--124 by J R M Hosking: "L-moments: Analysis and Estimation of Distribution using Linear Combination of Order Statistics", page 109:

> An alternative justification of these interpretations of L-moments
>   may be based on the work of Oja (1981), Oja defined intuitively
>   reasonable criteria for one probability distribution on the real line
>   to be located further to the right (more dispersed, more skew, more
>   kurtotic) than another. A real-valued functional of a distribution
>   that preserves the partial ordering of distributions implied by these
>   criteria may then reasonably be called a 'measure of location
>   (dispersion, skewness, kurtosis)'. It follows immediately from Oja's
>   work that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ , in Oja's notation, $\mu(F)$
>   and $\frac12 \sigma_1(F)$, are measures of location and scale
>   respectively. Hosking (1989) shows that $\tau_3$ and $\tau_4$ are, by
>   Oja's criteria, measures of skewness and kurtosis respectively.

(For the moment, I refer to the paper for the definitions of these measures, they are all based on L-moments.)  The interesting thing is that, the traditional measure of kurtosis, based on fourth moments, is **not** a measure of kurtosis in the sense of Oja!  (I will edit in references for that claim when I can find it).

Comment: No problem with use of graphical and other techniques to understand distributional properties, but the statement that "skewness and kurtosis are practically worthless" is hyperbole. Both have great effects on all kinds of statistical inference.

Comment: @Peter It was probably meant "empirical kurtosis" in that statement.

Comment: Even so, empirical kurtosis tells you when you have an outlier problem in your data. So I still think the comment "skewness and kurtosis are practically worthless" is hyperbole. Sure, they might not be great estimates of the "population" parameters, especially with smaller sample sizes, but "practically worthless" is a stretch.  Even if they do not estimate the population parameters particularly well, they still provide useful descriptive information about the existing data set. Information that, of course, should be supplemented by graphical views such as qq plots.

Comment: @Peter Westfall: The real Q is maybe if empirical kurtosis is the best measure there is to detect outlier problems, or if there is something better?

Comment: Empirical kurtosis measures the outlier character of a data set, not individual outliers. I would not go so far as to say that kurtosis = 3 (like normal) means "no outliers," but I would say that such a case means that the outlier character (as measured by average z-value, each taken to the fourth power) is similar to that of a normal distribution. On the other hand, a huge kurtosis most certainly indicates an outlier problem. Yes, normal q-q plots are better for more refined diagnosis. BTW, the normal q-q plot and the excess kurtosis have a firm mathematical connection.

Comment: Here is the link for the math connection between excess kurtosis and the normal q-q plot: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262453/does-this-q-q-plot-indicates-leptokurtic-or-platykurtic-distribution/354076#354076

Answer (score 3):

I my opinion, the skewness coefficient is useful to motivate the terms: positively skewed and negatively skewed. But, that is where it stops, if your goal is to assess normality. Classical measures of skewness and kurtosis often fail to capture various types of deviation away from normality. I usually advocate to my students to use graphical techniques to assess it is reasonable to assess normality, such as a qq-plot or a normal probability plot. Also with an adequately sized sample, a histogram can also be used. Boxplots are also useful to identify outliers or even heavy tails.

This is inline with the recommendations a 1999 task force of the APA:

"**Assumptions.** *You should take efforts to assure that the underlying assumptions required for the analysis are reasonable given the data. Examine residuals carefully. Do not use distributional tests and statistical indexes of
shape (e.g., skewness, kurtosis) as a substitute for examining your residuals 'graphically. Using a statistical test to diagnose problems in model
fitting has several shortcomings. First, diagnostic significance tests based on summary statistics (such as tests for homogeneity of variance) are often impractically sensitive; our statistical tests of models are often more robust than our statistical tests of assumptions. Second, statistics such as skewness and kurtosis often fail to detect distributional irregularities in the residuals. Third, statistical tests depend on sample size, and as sample size increases, the tests often will reject innocuous assumptions. In general, there is no substitute for graphical analysis of assumptions.*"

Reference: 
Wilkinson, L., & Task Force on Statistical Inference. (1999). Statistical methods in psychology journals: Guidelines and explanations. American Psychologist, 54, 594-604.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how applied the course is, the question of accuracy of estimates might come up. The accuracy of the variance estimate depends strongly on kurtosis. The reason this happens is that with high kurtosis, the distribution allows rare, extreme potentially observable data. Thus the data-generating process will produce very extreme values in some samples, and not so extreme values in others. In the former case, you get a very large variance estimate, and in the latter, a small variance estimate.

If the outdated and incorrect "peakedness" interpretation were eliminated, and the focus given entirely to outliers (i.e., rare, extreme observables) instead, then it would be easier to teach kurtosis in introductory courses. But people twist themselves into knots trying to justify "peakedness" because it is (incorrectly) stated that way in their textbooks, and they miss the real applications of kurtosis. These applications mostly relate to outliers, and of course outliers are important in applied statistics courses.

Comment: Are you the same Peter Westfall as the author of the most upvoted answer in this thread? If so, you could have your profiles merged together and then directly edit your old answer instead of posting another answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry for missing the netiquette.

Answer (score -1):

Frankly, I don't understand why people want to complicate simple things. Why not just show the definition (stolen from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis)):
$$\operatorname{Kurt}[X] = \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^4\right] = \frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4} = \frac{\operatorname{E}[(X-\mu)^4]}{(\operatorname{E}[(X-\mu)^2])^2},
$$

You can replace the expectation operator with sum based estimators $\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n$, of course. It helps to discuss the units of measure of $\mu,\sigma^2,\mu_4$, and show why the fourth moment should be scaled by the square of the variance to make kurtosis the dimensionless measure, i.e. a shape parameter. So, we have now location $\mu$, scale $\sigma^2$ and any number of parameters to describe the shape such as skew and kurtosis. I'd always start with equations. Supposedly easy to understand explanations in plain English only make everything more confusing. Verbosity $\ne$ clarity.

Comment: The problem is that, once you get the kurtosis, it's very unintuitive what (if anything) it means.  It doesn't match up with useful qualities of the distribution.

Comment: Yes, kurtosis does match with a very useful quality of a distribution - it is a measure of tailweight (outliers). Supporting mathematical theorems, for which there is no counterexample: (i) kurtosis is between E(Z^4 *I(|Z| >1)) and E(Z^4 *I(|Z| >1)) + 1, for all distributions having finite 4th moment. (ii) for the subclass of continuous distributions where the density of Z^2 is decreasing on (0,1), kurtosis is between E(Z^4 *I(|Z| >1)) and E(Z^4 *I(|Z| >1)) + .5, and (iii) for any sequence of distributions with kurtosis tending to infinity,  E(Z^4 *I(|Z| >b))/kurtosis ->1, for every real b.