# Standard skew / kurtosis distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, skewness, kurtosis

What is the common choice of distribution to fit skewed data? I am in the process of studying the effect of skew on qqplot (and varies other). So I want to know the standard version of skewed distribution.

1. Ideally it should have mean, variance parameter just like a normal distribution. But an extra skewness control parameter.
2. Ideally it should have 1st, 2nd, 3rd moment non-zero, but every other moment above are 0.

Does such distribution exist? I find skewed normal, but it seems overly complex and does not have 4th moment =0.

Same applies to a $\text{standard kurtosis} \not= 0$ distribution, where we can set kurtosis freely. Does such distribution exist?

Comment: I’m wondering if you could construct such a distribution via moment-generating functions.

Comment: Why those moment requirements? Besides, they are **impossible**. You probably meant cumulants.

Comment: The only distributions with zero fourth (central) moments are constant; for them, all central moments beyond the first are zero.

Comment: @kjetil even with setting higher order cumulants to 0, it's not going to work: the normal distribution is the only (nontrivial) distribution having a finite number of non-zero cumulants, so having a distribution with non-zero 3rd cumulant but all higher cumulants zero is also impossible.

Comment: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cumulants#Uniqueness

Comment: The OP concerns effects of skew and kurtosis on q-q plots.  Here is a link showing a direct mathematical connection in the case of kurtosis.  Similar algebra can be developed for skewness.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262453/does-this-q-q-plot-indicates-leptokurtic-or-platykurtic-distribution/354076#354076