# Replicate distribution image kurtosis

Tags: kurtosis

I am trying to replicate one of the images from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/how-is-the-kurtosis-of-a-distribution-related-to-the-geometry-of-the-density-fun/143522#143522) post.

In particular I want to plot something similar to this image in matlab:

[image]

I.e. I  want these three differently peaked distributions, where the tails are very clear. Can someone help me with such a plot?

Code as of now:

```
y = normpdf(x,0,1);
plot(x,y)
y1 = tpdf(x,5);
hold on 
plot(x,y1)
hold on 
y2 = tpdf(x,1000)
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to explain what software you are using, here I think MATLAB,  A $t$ distribution with 1000 df will be hard to distinguish from a normal distribution and does not in any case have lower kurtosis. A more basic pitfall for e.g. a $t$ distribution with 5 df has variance 5/3 compared with your normal which has variance 1.  Hence a graph conflates different kurtosis and different variance, although that problem is soluble by scaling by SD.

Answer (score 1):

The referenced post and graphic are misleading because they suggest that kurtosis somehow measures height and/or pointiness/flatness of the distribution, notions which have been thoroughly debunked. Rather, kurtosis is a measure of tailweight (or more specifically tail *leverage*), see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/481022/102879 for a good place to start.

It *is* important to visualize the heaviness of the tails, but the standard histogram/density plot is inadequate for this purpose: The tails, even when heavy, are too close to zero to distinguish "light" from "heavy" in such graphs.  Instead, you can use the normal quantile-quantile plot. Tail heaviness is very easy to see in this plot, and there is a direct mathematical connection between the appearance of this plot and the kurtosis statistic.  See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354076/102879

Comment: A log scale for density can help too.