# Calculate $ E(Y) $ when $ Y = max(X, 2\theta - X ) $

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

Calculate $ E(Y) $  when $ Y = max(X, 2\theta - X ) $ when  $ X $ ~ $  Uniform U( 0 , 2\theta ) . $

To this question,  one of my classmates answered like this
Let $ A = X , B = 2\theta - X $

$ E(Max(A,B) = E(\frac{A+B}{2}) +E(\frac{A-B}{2}) $

$ E(Max(A,B) = E(\frac{2\theta }{2}) +E(\frac{2X + \theta }{2}) $

$ E(Max(A,B) = \theta  +E(X) + E(\theta) $

$ E(Max(A,B) = 2\theta  +E(X)   $

**And carried on the calculations  , now , I dont know this concept of adding and subtracting A,B
Can someone please explain the basis of it ???**

Comment: Please add the self-study tag.

Comment: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/expected-value-of-max-function)

Comment: Hint: $2\theta-Y$ has the same distribution as $Y.$  That leads *immediately* to the answer with no calculation required.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46843 for details.  The duplicate addresses your question about "adding and subtracting" random variables.